# Show that $X \perp Y|Z,W$ and $X \perp W | Z,Y$ implies $X \perp Y|Z$ and $X \perp W|Z$

Tags: probability, independence

Given random variables $X,Y,Z,W$ where $X \perp Y|Z,W$ and $X \perp W | Z,Y$ ($\perp$ symbols independence), show that $X \perp Y|Z$ and $X \perp W|Z$.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ is common in both conditions, we can calculate  $P(X|Y,Z,W)$ in 2 ways. $$P(X|Y,Z,W)=\frac{P(X,Y|Z,W)}{P(Y|Z,W)}=\frac{P(X,W|Z,Y)}{P(W|Z,Y)}$$
From the independence, we get $P(X|Z,W)=P(X|Z,Y)$.

Then 
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X|Z)*P(Y|Z) &= \frac{P(X,Z)*P(Y,Z)}{P^2(Z)} \\ 
&=\frac{\sum_WP(W,X,Z)*P(Y,Z)}{P^2(Z)} \\
&=\frac{\sum_WP(Z,W)*P(X|Z,W)*P(Y,Z)}{P^2(Z)}\\
&=\frac{\sum_WP(Z,W)*P(X|Y,Z)*P(Y,Z)}{P^2(Z)}\\
&=\frac{P(Z)*P(X,Y,Z)}{P^2(Z)}\\
&=P(X,Y|Z)
\end{align*}$$