# How to prove $X \perp Y \mid Z$ and $X \perp Z \mid Y$ implies $X \perp \{Y, Z\}$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be random variables. I learn from theorem 17.2 of the book All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman that under the assumption that the probability of the joint distribution $(X,Y,Z)$ is everywhere positive, $X \perp Y \mid Z$ and $X \perp Z \mid Y$ implies $X \perp \{Y, Z\}$. But I could not prove it. Could anyone help?

$X \perp Y \mid Z$ means $X$ is independent of $Y$ conditionally on $Z$, similarly $X \perp Z \mid Y$. $X \perp \{Y, Z\}$ means $X$ is independent of both $Y$ and $Z$.

In the book itself, the assumption is termed "all events have positive probability". Since it might be confusing where "events" come from, I translate it as the "the probability of the joint distribution $(X,Y,Z)$ is everywhere positive".

Comment: Could you clearify you question? Are $X,Y,Z$ events? What do you mean by $X \perp Y \mid Z$?

Comment: @mag Hi, I just added some clarifications to the question

Comment: _What_ are the events that are assumed to have positive probabilities?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am taking the assumption from the book itself so I use "events". I think it means the probability of the joint distribution $(X,Y,Z)$ are always positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the question to be identical to [Show that $X \perp Y|Z,W$ and $X \perp W | Z,Y$ implies $X \perp Y|Z$ and $X \perp W|Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217797/show-that-x-perp-yz-w-and-x-perp-w-z-y-implies-x-perp-yz-and-x-pe). The proof looks like this.

Since $X \perp Y \mid Z$ and $X \perp Z \mid Y$, $P(X\mid Y,Z)$ can be written in two ways,

\begin{align}
P(X\mid Y,Z) = P(X \mid Y) = P(X \mid Z)
\end{align}

Using the above equality,
\begin{align}
P(X)P(Y) 
&= \int_{Z}P(Z)P(X\mid Z)P(Y) \\
&= \int_{Z}P(Z)P(X\mid Y)P(Y) \\
&=P(X,Y)
\end{align}

Thus, $X \perp Y$. $X \perp Z$ can be shown in the same way.